# Hot reloading with Mobx React decorators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

As stated in [MobX FAQ](https://www.mobxjs.com/faq/faq.html),

> Is React Native supported?
>
> Yes, mobx and mobx-react will work on React Native. The latter through
> importing "mobx-react/native". The devtools don't support React
> Native. Note that if you indend to use your observer components with
> hot reloading, decorators in the components may not always work. If
> that is the case, use the functions instead (eg. action(fn) instead of
> @action or observer(component) instead of @observer).

I have doubts because FAQ also mentions that *MobX runs on any ES5 environment*, while this is applicable to MobX 4 and lower.

- What is the problem with hot reloading and decorators?
- Is the problem still relevant?
- Is it specific to React and MobX combination?
- Is it applicable to React Native only, and why?
- Does a workaround suggest `this.method = action(fn)`, or `ComponentClass.prototype.method = action(fn)`?
- Can it be worked around with MobX [`decorate`](https://www.mobxjs.com/refguide/api.html#decorate)?